# Facing issue in facing storing data into factory and use it in different controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new angular, started using it from 2 months and now in my project, I need to migrate from Angularjs to Angular. So I need to re-write whole code into Angular. I see previous developer used so many $rootScopes to store value and use that value in other controllers. I am trying to use services for that so that I can easily migrate to Angular.
Please see my code and let me know what mistake I did. [plnkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/yhyeTCfX7PpPgsxv93te)

Here is the code where I created factory services and that service I am trying to access in other controllers.
app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.factory('Data', function(){
  return {message: "I'm a data from a Service"}
});
```

first.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
       .controller(FirstCtrl, function($scope, $rootScope){
         $scope.data = Data;

       });
```

second.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
       .controller(SecondCtrl, function($scope){
         $scope.data = Data;
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject your factory into controllers.
Heres docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

And it should look like this:

App.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('Data', function(){
  return {message: "I'm a data from a Service"}
});

app.controller('FirstCtrl', ['$scope', 'Data', function($scope, Data){
  $scope.data = Data.message;
}]);
```

And html file:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Services</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Services</h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller ="FirstCtrl">
      {{data}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey thanks for your help. Its like no one wants to help new developers. I appreciate that

Comment: this is also not working. I implemented same. But I got new concept

Comment: its says ctrl is not defined

Comment: Well, you are setting ng-app in the wrong spot. It needs to be in the parent element of your controllers, usually <body> or <html> elements. Also there were some spelling errors, attaching the fixed code to the answer now :)

Comment: I have given plnkr link. Is it possible for you to try there. Its also not working for me. Don't know whats the issue

Comment: Also I was doing it just to understand the concept of services. Now I got that. Just wanted to know instead of all rootScopes should I use same concept? It will be so many services then?

Comment: Heres a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ft77Ugb2HDSGD6zPm3wX

Service/factory/provider (which are preety much the same in angular1) can return an object with multiple functions/properities/objects. You could preety much practically pack everything into one factory, but its a good idea to split functions that do wildly different stuff into separate factories.

Comment: for login authentication look how rootscopes are being used in my project.                                 AuthenticationService.Login(this.loginData.username, this.loginData.password, function (response) {
    if(response){
     if (response.statusCode == 0) {
      $rootScope.usrData.userDisplayName = response.userDisplayName;
      $rootScope.usrData.userSessionId = response.sessionkey;

Comment: Not sure what the question is there, but in most cases you should be able to use factory as a replacement for rootScope without chaning the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final link. Just an tutorial for new developers like me to use services for data sharing between two controllers:-

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('Data', function(){
  return {message: "I'm a data from a Service", error: "Hey, i have errored :)"}
});

app.controller('FirstCtrl', ['$scope', 'Data', function($scope, Data){
  $scope.data = Data;
}]);
```

[plnkr link here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ft77Ugb2HDSGD6zPm3wX?p=preview)